# How to Change this Title after i replace a Fragment?

Tags: android

[image: d]
[image]

> Here is my HomeFragment.java:

```
gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GAL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new GalleryFragment(), "GalleryFragmentTag");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    }
});
```

> Also, GalleryFragment.java is

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("Team B");
    gallery_recycler_view= root.findViewById(R.id.gallery_recycler_view);
}
```

> Here is my MainActivity.java :

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send,R.id.nav_notifications)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

> Any Feedback is Appreciated.
>   I am new to Fragments 
>   It is asking me to add more details
>   Here is more details 
>   Here is more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your `Fragment`, `onResume` method you can change the toolbar title like following

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Set title
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Your Title");
}
```

Comment: but when i press the Back Button, the same title is in HomeFragment also. How can it be fixed ?

Comment: Updated the post check it once. and accept the answer. Cheers